# Where to set props-dependant state in a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, state

Let's say that I want to set the initial state of a component depending on a variable from the parent that is passed via `props`.

```
class MyClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
```

I want to set the state like this:

```
if (this.props.foo === 'bar') {
  this.setState({foo: 'bar'});
} else {
  this.setState({foo: 'notBar'});
}
```

I put it in `ComponentDidMount()` and it seems to work. However, should I move it to the constructor and use the syntax `this.state = {...}`? Or does it belong to `ComponentWillMount()`? If so, is there a guarantee that the state will be rendered in time? (`foo` is displayed as a text field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your state is assigned based on the value of proper, a good place to handle it is to assign it in the two places

1. ComponentWillMount/Constructor/ComponentDidMount: These are executed only once, when the component is mounted. One more thing is that if you setState in componentWillMount or componentDidMount, the it should be atleast initialised in contructor so that you don't get an undefined state error.
2. ComponentWillReceiveProps: This lifeCyle function is not called at the time of mounting but everytime after that the parent rerenders, so any time the prop foo changes from parent , it can be assigned to state again here

Do it like

```
constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
         foo: ''
     }
}
componentWillMount(){
    if (this.props.foo === 'bar') {
          this.setState({foo: 'bar'});
    } else {
         this.setState({foo: 'notBar'});
    }
}
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
   if (nextProps.foo === 'bar') {
          this.setState({foo: 'bar'});
    } else {
         this.setState({foo: 'notBar'});
    }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of ``componentWillReceiveProps()``, thanks! So if I understand it correctly, using ``componentWillReceiveProps()`` would, in practice, yield a similar result as passing ``getFoo()`` as props instead of ``foo``? (where ``getFoo()`` is a parent method that returns the ``foo`` value read from the parent state)

Comment: Kind of similar, but can be used to handle many ,more props at once

Comment: Okay, I had been using the approach of passing getter functions as props all the time, so it's good to know a cleaner alternative. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to have helped, I would suggest you to go through the React DOCs to know more about lifcycle function. They help a lot

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is valid to initialize state in the constructor: [React Constructor Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#constructor)

So your code would be as follows:

```
class MyClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    if (props.foo === 'bar') {
      this.state = {foo: 'bar'};
    } else {
      this.state = {foo: 'notBar'};
    }
  }
}
```

However, be aware that any change to the props in the parent will not be updated in this component, since it's only set on the constructor.

So this is only a good way to initialize state if you do not expect the parent props to change (but that is probably rare). Have a look at [Lifting State Up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html) for a guide to architect your components in a better way.